# Format Document - Configure prettierrc like built in formatter of VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, prettier, react-typescript

I like to format documents with VSCode built-in features, which are convenient, don't depend on extensions, simplicity, and have suitable functionality of these built-in.

For example, this is a React Typescript project.

However, when the project keeps growing, I should not require everyone to add to their `settings.json` configuration like below because they are also working on other projects using other plenty format rules.

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
```

So I want to configure the `.prettierrc` file to make the Prettier format properties approximately like the `vscode.typescript-language-features` format properties. I have looked for the `vscode.typescript-language-features` format properties but have not found it, could I achieve this solution? Or are there any other ways?